# PHP submit buttons/structure?

Tags: php

here is a bit of code im working on. Everything works expect that part where i enter ID, then it shows me information in that ID row and also 2 boxes pop where i can write new value of variable. There is also 2 buttons, one which comfirms the edit which has been written into boxes and second one to delete that row from database.

Im still at kinda basics at programming as you can see and im quessing there is something wrong with structure in this part of code?

Can anyone help me to make these 2 submit buttons work as they should.

Thanks you all. :)

```
if(isset($_POST['idnumber'])) {
$idnumber = protect($_POST['idnumber']);
global $idnumber;
if($idnumber == ""){
    echo "Please supply all fields!";
}
else{ 
    ?>
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <br />
    <tr>
        <td width="50px"><b>ID</b></td>
        <td width="150px"><b>Current name</b></td>
        <td width="200px"><b>Current description</b></td>
        <td width="100px"><b>Time added</b></td>
        <td width="100px"><b>Current status</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $get_tasks = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM task WHERE id='$idnumber'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_tasks)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        $get_taskname = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT taskname FROM task WHERE id='$idnumber'") or die(mysql_error());
        $task_name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_taskname);
        echo "<td>" . $task_name['taskname'] . "</td>"; 
        $get_description = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT description FROM task WHERE id='$idnumber'") or die(mysql_error());
        $description_text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_description);
        echo "<td>" . $description_text['description'] . "</td>";
        $get_dateadded = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT dateadded FROM task WHERE id='$idnumber'") or die(mysql_error());
        $date_added = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_dateadded);
        echo "<td>" . $date_added['dateadded'] . "</td>";
        $get_status = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT status FROM task WHERE id='$idnumber'") or die(mysql_error());
        $cur_status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_status);
        if($cur_status['status'] == 1) {
            echo "<td>" . "Unfinished" . "</td>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<td>" . "Finished" . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['edittask'])) {
        $editname = protect($_POST['editname']);
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE task SET taskname=$editname WHERE id='$idnumber'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['deletetask'])) {
        mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM task WHERE id='$idnumber'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        ?>     
    <form action="test2.php" method="POST" >
        <td width="50px"><b></b></td>
        <td width="150px"><b>New name: <input type="text" name="editname"/></b></td>
        <td width="200px"><b>New desc: <input type="text" name="editdesc"/></b></td>
        <td width="100px"><b></b></td>
        <td width="100px"><b>D</b></td>

    <input type="submit" name="edittask" value="Edit task"/> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="deletetask" value="Delete task"/> <br />
    </form>

    <?php
    }
}     
        ?>
</table>
<br /><br />
<form action="test2.php" method="POST" >
Insert ID of task to edit: <input type="text" name="idnumber"/>
<input type="submit" name="ids" value="Find task"/> <br />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. What's not working? In any case "UPDATE task SET taskname=$editname WHERE id='$idnumber'" should be `"UPDATE task SET taskname=$editname, description='".$_POST['editdesc']."' WHERE id='$idnumber'"`

Comment: `mysql_error` doesn't work with `mysqli`. You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: http://pho.to/AAvGA/2e     when i enter ID and press find task ill get information: http://pho.to/AAvGA/t2     but when i enter new information and press edit task or delete task it dosnt do anything. Yeah, gonna change mysql in a moment.